# Is there a version of the Dark Knight where Batman keeps shouting "Where is Rachel!!?"?

Tags: alternate-version, the-dark-knight

I watched the Dark Knight when I was in school. I specifically remember that during the interrogation scene, the Batman keeps shouting "Where is Rachel?" in order to get Rachel's location.

For some reason, years later, when I watched the movie again, I did not find this line. Are there various versions of the interrogation scene with the Joker?

Comment: "Where is she!?" has always been the line. Perhaps you are affected by the Mandela effect or since this line was paraodied and meme'd you remember something else.

Comment: Rachel Dawes....can we trust her?